# .net core 3.1 - View Components - Not finding my Default.cshtml

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm just getting to grips with ViewComponents in my Razor pages application.

I have a ViewComponents folder within my project that contains my ViewComponent .cs code:

```
 public class RemoveFromCartViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {  
       
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
             
            var result = "123";    
            return View(result);    

        }   
    
    }
```

I then have another folder within Pages/Shared/Components called **RemoveFromCart**. Within this folder I have my default.cshtml

```
@model string

<h2>
    @Model
</h2>
```

Simply putting the string within a h2 tag.

In my projects Layout.cshtml file I am invoking this ViewComponent:

```
   <div>
          @await Component.InvokeAsync("RemoveFromCart") 
   </div>
```

When I start my project, the error I get is:

```
*InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/RemoveFromCart/123' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Pages/Components/RemoveFromCart/123.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Components/RemoveFromCart/123.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Components/RemoveFromCart/123.cshtml*
```

This is indication my view should be called 123.cshtml which doesnt seem right. What am I doing wrong here? I should simply expect to see the text 123 appear

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning `View("123")`, you are using [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponent.view?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewComponent_View_System_String_):

> #### `public ViewViewComponentResult View (string viewName)`
>
> Returns a result which will render the partial view with name viewName.

So you are passing the view name, instead of a string value as the view’s model.

You can change that by explicitly calling the [`View<TModel>(TModel)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponent.view?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewComponent_View__1___0_) overload instead:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
    var result = "123";    
    return View<string>(result);    
}
```

In the long run, I would suggest you to create a model class instead so that you can pass an object instead of just a string. This will avoid having this particular problem and you are also able to easily expand the model contents later on.